# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm

When I want to create new user via terminal I got this error :

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be null
```

I am using MySQL database and Doctrine 2.5 as ORM. 
Here is setting of the table:

```
Column  Type    Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
name    varchar(255)     
created_at  datetime     
last_login  datetime NULL
```

And here is create_user.php:

```
<?php
// create_user.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
require_once "bootstrap.php";
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Db\User;

$newUsername = $argv[1];

$user = new User();
$user->setName($newUsername);

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created User with ID " . $user->getId() . "\n";
```

User.php :

```
<?php
// src/User.php
namespace Db;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="user")
**/
class User
{
/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") **/
protected $created_at;

/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) **/
protected $last_login;
```

I can't see the error because column created_at isn't null.

Comment: What query are you running?

Comment: Code in comments is almost impossible to read. Please edit the question to include that code.

Comment: Where do you set created at?

Comment: Show the SQL that is being executed that causes this error not the php.  before the SQL runs, write out the statement and update the question with that detail.  If you're getting `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be null` returned, you can darn well bet that the SQL being passed lacks a  created_at value which is required for the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set any value to `created_at`, so it throws an error. Either set your `created_at` to nullable or set the value explicitly in your code:

```
$user->setCreatedAt((new \DateTime()));
```

Comment: This was the problem. If I make it nullable it works but I want to add the current date of creating of user how can I do it?

Comment: It is already in my answer - you need to call `$user->setCreatedAt((new \DateTime()));` - this will set the `createdAt` to the current DateTime.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Db\User::setCreatedAt() in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_user.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_user.php on line 12

Comment: Do ou have `setCreatedAt` method in your Entity class? If not then you need to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You should complete the definition of the `created_at` column with `NOT NULL`. In the create table syntax would be like:

```
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
```

Then each default value for the `created_at` column will be set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.